# Capture Screen Video in iOS, especially iPad Ratina

Tags: ios, uiview, screenshot, calayer, video-capture

In one of my iPad app, I need to add the ability to record everything on the screen and create a video. I found the great ScreenCaptureView here: http://aroth.no-ip.org:82/wordpress/archives/673, and it does work. But it performs badly on my iPad 4. After profiling with Instruments, I find the pain point to be the "renderInContext" call every 100ms (10frame/s by default) to get the current screen shot.

I then googled and tried a lot, such as using [[self.layer representationLayer] renderInContext:context], and even the private API UIGetScreenImage(). But they all have bad performance. The renderInContext method call can take more than 300ms each time. :(

So, Is there any high performance method to get the current screenshot image? Or is there better video capturing method than the one listed above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try tho VTMScreenRecorderTest. I have used it and works great. !!!

http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2011/04/

Hope It helped..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's almost using the same method I used. And it's also using the renderInContext method to get the screenshot. Does it work great on iPad 4?